# Xcode (Objective C) -- Label movement

Tags: objective-c, animation, label

Whats the best way to animate a Label?

I'm trying to get a label to fade in to view and slide across a cell into its resting position when the view loads.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no best way or worst way when you don't even mention your development platform.

Comment: Hi -- thanks for the quick response. iOS 8.4 / Xcode 7.0.

Comment: See UIView animateWithDuration here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:.

Comment: Awesome -- cheers danh. :)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is jazz-hands check it out -> https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands but i do agree with El Tomato there is no best way or worst way just preferences.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems a bit much for what i want to achieve though.